# Running Selenium & Firefox & geckodriver on Raspberry Pi 2 Model B

Tags: arm, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to run Selenium on my Raspberry Pi 2 Model B but I'm having trouble finding a compatible combination of versions of Selenium, Firefox, and geckodriver.

(I've already run `sudo apt-get update`, `upgrade` and `dist-upgrade`.)

1. **Using "old" Selenium** like 2.53.1 (`pip3 install selenium==2.53.1`) produces the "can't load the profile" error:

   ```
   $ uname -a ; firefox --version ; python3 --version ; python3 -c "import selenium ; print(\"Selenium: \" + selenium.__version__)" ; xvfb-run python3 -c "from selenium import webdriver ; browser = webdriver.Firefox()"

   Linux raspberrypi 4.1.19+ #858 Tue Mar 15 15:52:03 GMT 2016 armv6l GNU/Linux
   Mozilla Firefox 45.9.0
   Python 3.2.3
   Selenium: 2.53.1
   Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
     File "/home/pi/.virtualenv/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 103, in __init__
       self.binary, timeout)
     File "/home/pi/.virtualenv/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/extension_connection.py", line 51, in __init__
       self.binary.launch_browser(self.profile, timeout=timeout)
     File "/home/pi/.virtualenv/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 68, in launch_browser
       self._wait_until_connectable(timeout=timeout)
     File "/home/pi/.virtualenv/python3.2.3/lib/python3.2/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/firefox_binary.py", line 106, in _wait_until_connectable
       % (self.profile.path))
   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Can't load the profile. Profile Dir: /tmp/tmpv2bdep If you specified a log_file in the FirefoxBinary constructor, check it for details.
   ```

(Note: Increasing the timeout in `firefox_binary.py` as described [here](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1300) didn't change the error.)

The standard response to this error is to use a modern version of Selenium. However:

2. **Using "new" Selenium** like 3.7 (`pip3 install --upgrade selenium`) [requires geckodriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/tree/master/py#drivers), which [requires Firefox 55+](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver#supported-firefoxen), but  my package manager only provides Firefox 45:

   ```
   $ apt-cache policy firefox-esr
   firefox-esr:
     Installed: 45.9.0esr-1~deb7u1
     Candidate: 45.9.0esr-1~deb7u1
     Version table:
    *** 45.9.0esr-1~deb7u1 0
           500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy/main armhf Packages
           100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
   ```

Additionally, geckodriver doesn't offer an ARM6 binary in their [Releases](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases), and when I try to build it from source, I get an error that my glibc is too old:

```
/home/pi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/rustc: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /home/pi/.rustup/toolchains/stable-arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf/bin/../lib/../lib/../lib/librustc_llvm-d6e9fbf157b3f888.so)
```

(Running `ldd --version` tells me I'm running glibc version `Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u12) 2.13`.)

Lastly, a thoughtful redditor [posted ARM6-compiled versions of geckodriver](https://www.reddit.com/r/raspberry_pi/comments/70ntpf/i_compiled_geckodriver_for_armv6_and_it_is_working/), but these result in errors about my glibc version as well:

```
./geckodriver: /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.18' not found (required by ./geckodriver)
```

I tried using Chromium instead of Firefox, but Selenium requires `chromedriver` which isn't available on ARM 6.

So I guess my question is:

**Is there a way to run Selenium and Firefox on a Raspberry Pi 2 Model B?**

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

I got a working configuration:

- bought a $35 [Raspberry Pi 3 from Adafruit](https://www.adafruit.com/product/3055)

  - Ships with Python 3.5.3
  - `lscpu` shows it runs ARM7 cpu architecture (required by geckodriver)
- Using OS: [Raspbian based on Debian Stretch](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/raspbian/) (Sep 7, 2017, linux kernel v4.9)
- Firefox 52.5.0 (`sudo apt-get install firefox-esr`)
- [geckodriver v0.17.0 for ARM7](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/download/v0.17.0/geckodriver-v0.17.0-arm7hf.tar.gz)

Note: Don't use the latest geckodriver -- you need to pick the one that matches your version of Firefox. This is hard because the geckodriver release notes aren't consistent about saying which version of Firefox and Selenium they're compatible with.

Comment: try with geckodriver 0.17, firefox 56, latest selenium

Comment: @ArpitAgarwal, thanks for the suggestion. However, as the post explains, geckodriver produces a glibc incompatibility error and firefox 56 isn't available in the Raspbian package manager. Is there a way around this?

Comment: In debian and it's derivative, firefox is `iceweasel`

Comment: As for `gblic` you are using an outdated release. Upgrade to `stretch`. I am running `jessie` and my `glibc` version is **2.19**

Comment: On my machine, both `firefox` and `iceweasel` point to `firefox-esr`. I think you are correct that I will have to upgrade to Debian Stretch. The Raspbian docs advise rebuilding a fresh installation instead of upgrading, which means I'll have to rebuild my whole system. Is there another way? That's a pain!

Comment: No, there is no other way. You can make a script that will does the configuration.

Comment: I agree with you martian, most of the problems related to this error are compatibility issues. downgrading to geckodriver v0.17.0 solves it for me.

Comment: Your update really help me. I'm using Raspberry 3 model b with firefox 52.8.0 and the geckodriver 0.17.
A lot of thanks.

Comment: Also see [Geckodriver | Issue 950, Can't compile for ARMv6](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/950), [Geckodriver | Issue 1540, Error: Expected argument for flag '--target' but reached end of arguments](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1540) and [Cargo Issue 6836 | Error: environment variable `OUT_DIR` not defined on ARMv7](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/6836). The best I can tell things are still a mess. The Cargo folks say their stuff will be fixed when Debian Buster is released. I think that will be sometime in 2019 or 2020.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same but on Raspberry Pi 3B running Raspbian Buster.

I did a search through the whole root partition and realized that there is a ARM compatible version of geckodriver here:

`/opt/Wolfram/WolframEngine/12.0/SystemFiles/Components/WebUnit/Resources/DriverBinaries/GeckoDriver/Linux-ARM`

I should point out that I am running the desktop version of raspbian with the "full" desktop.

I had also seen suggestion to check the geckodriver github page but it looks like they no longer offer an ARM binary so this worked out for me.

I also haven't tried this but it's another option: https://github.com/d0ku/GeckoDriver_ARMv6

**NOTE:** According to this answer: [Raspberry Pi Zero W is ARMv6 or ARMv7?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/83374/raspberry-pi-zero-w-is-armv6-or-armv7), ARMv7 processors are backward compatible so I'm assuming you could use the Github link above with a more modern Pi as well.