# Raspberry Pi Zero W is ARMv6 or ARMv7?

Tags: hardware

I would like update Node.js to the latest version and I need to choose between ARMv6 and ARMv7. From the package manager point of view this is an ARMv6 processor and `dmesg` tells it is

```
CPU: ARMv6-compatible processor [410fb767] revision 7 (ARMv7)
```

so...  probably ARMv7.

Googling, I saw lot of people used ARMv7 without problem. But is it correct?

Comment: **ALL** Raspbian code (except for kernel) is ARM6, even though Pi2 and up CAN run ARM7, this depends on library support.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

First: It's ARMv6.

The Zero uses the original BCM2835 SoC used on the first generation of Pi's and all the other single core models, with a ARM1176JZF-S processor (although the Zero models have ones [binned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_binning) as 1000 Mhz instead of 700).

All ARM11 cores use the ARMv6 instruction set architecture.  Since those using ARMv7 or 8 are backward compatible with ARMv6, Raspbian has stuck with that. This is also the reason most of the distros used on the multicore models cannot be used on the Zero -- because they are ARMv7.

Answer (score 13):

According to the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi#Specifications), these are the instruction sets used for each Pi model:

- `Armv6-M`

  - Raspberry Pi Pico
  - Raspberry Pi Pico W
- `ARMv6Z` (32-bit)

  - Raspberry Pi 1 Model A
  - Raspberry Pi 1 Model A+
  - Raspberry Pi 1 Model B
  - Raspberry Pi 1 Model B+
  - Compute Module 1
  - Raspberry Pi Zero PCB v1.2
  - Raspberry Pi Zero PCB v1.3
  - Raspberry Pi Zero W
- `ARMv7-A` (32-bit)

  - Raspberry Pi 2 Model B
- `ARMv8-A` (64/32-bit)

  - Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+
  - Raspberry Pi 2 Model B v1.2
  - Raspberry Pi 3 Model B
  - Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+
  - Raspberry Pi 4 Model B
  - Compute Module 3
  - Compute Module 3 Lite
  - Compute Module 3+
  - Compute Module 3+ Lite
  - Compute Module 4
  - Compute Module 4 Lite
  - Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W
  - Raspberry Pi 400
- `ARMv8.2-A` (64/32-bit)

  - Raspberry Pi 5

Comment: What's the difference between v6-M, v6z, v7-a, etc. The letter adjacent to the ARM version?

Comment: The numbers and letters differentiate different versions of the architecture. Wikipedia will give you the basics (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture_family). I Guess if you're interested in specifics you could dive into ARMs own docs (https://developer.arm.com/architectures)